# Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: PolymerExpressions is not defined

Tags: dart

I am using Dart SDK 1.4.2 and polymer 0.10.1+1

I am somewhat uncertain as to why I am getting the following console output

Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: PolymerExpressions is not defined

The Debugger refers to polymer.js and points to the polymer.js line below:

```
 Polymer={},"function"==typeof window.Polymer&&(Polymer={}),...
```

Here is the entry-point code - it is contained in the index.html that throws the exception.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ePIMSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/website.css">

  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

  <link rel='import' href='packages/epimss_polymer/components/menu/menu-form.html'>
  <script type="application/dart">
    export "package:polymer/init.dart";
  </script>
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   <!--<div><phone-row-form></phone-row-form></div> -->

<div><menu-form></menu-form></div>
</body>
```

My packages structure is shown in the graphic below

[image]

Comment: What's the code behind it?

Comment: Please see the html code in the answer below - it is NOT an answer, it just allows formatting of the code that the comment does not allow.

Comment: shouldn't packages/browser/dart.js be an the end of <body>?

Comment: Also isnt polymer/init.dart deprecated?

Comment: @Robert No. polymer/init.dart is not deprecated for polymer 0.10.1+1. Please see [link](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web/p2llvVOWEUI/Yo_siywqYWwJ). The packages/browser/dart.js is also as my reading suggest.

Comment: see [https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web/p2llvVOWEUI/Yo_siywqYWwJ].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56048/discussion-between-st-clair-clarke-and-robert).